# asymptotic bounds explain

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Can anyone explain me why:

1.

[image]

?

Comment: No, because it is incorrect.

Comment: Good. That's what i thought. So, is this big theta of logn?

Comment: Yes. Can you see why?

Comment: Yes. You can do this easily directly from the definition of big theta but you can say left side is equal to (1/2)log(2(pi)n). And after "ignoring" constants(1/2, 2, pi) its logn. Right?

Comment: Take care when removing constant multiplicative factors. In this example the result is correct because `½log(2πn) = ½log(n) + ½log(2π)`, and the last term can be ignored. But e.g. `exp(2πn)` cannot be simplified further.